# is it possible to read from ActiveMQ using Azure Logic App or Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, activemq-classic, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to read messages from ActiveMQ (inhouse) into Azure. 
Is there a possibility using Azure Logic Apps or Azure Functions ?

Regards
Prabath

Answer (score 0):

- With Logic Apps: not really.
- With Functions: It depends what you want to do. If you are looking to trigger a Function on new messages, like it does with Azure Event Hub etc, this is not built-in. You can partially get there by building a custom MQTT trigger. This is, however, not officially supported and even if you manage to build and run it, you won't get the built-in scaling logic of Functions.
  If you, however, want to read messages on demand, for example with a timer-triggered Function, this would technically be doable by using an MQTT library in your Function code and connect to your broker.

Besides all of this you of course need to make sure you'll establish network connectivity if the broker runs on-prem. Either by exposing that one on a public endpoint or by using VPN/ExpressRoute and using VNET-integrated Functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am looking at timer-triggered function only... I will have a look at MQTT libraries...

Comment: @user1872757 did you get this working with azure functions?